# Адаптируемый размер текста у Control JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, шрифты

Собственно уже n-ый день мучаюсь с размером шрифта. Вот ситуация: на обычный AnchorPane добавил обычную кнопку и поставил все якори по 30. Теперь, когда я буду изменять размер окна, размер кнопки будет меняться. Но вот размер шрифта не меняется! Попробовал уже следующие варианты.

1. Привязал слушатель к размеру Control'a и в зависимости от значений высоты и ширины менял размер шрифта. Но тут проблемой оказалось то, что когда вы уменьшаете размер окна, шрифт уже стал определённого размера и не даёт уменьшится Control'y, а следовательно и самому себе и таким образом он становится неуменьшаемым.
2. Дальше я попробовал использовать ScalableContentPane из JFXtras, но тут пробела с тем, что невозможно делать GUI в SceneBuilder, т.к. чтобы данный объект работал правильно нужно детей добавлять не на его, а на его ContentPane, который получается в коде так `new ScalableContentPane().getContentPane`, а ещё он странно изменял свой размер и смотрелось это так себе...

Такие дела... Жду ваших предложений и решений, если что-то непонятно - пишите, уточню. Вот на всякий случай код...

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FontSample extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    anchorPane.setPrefSize(900, 700);

    Button button = new Button("MrButton");
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(button, 30.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(button, 30.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(button, 30.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(button, 30.0);

    anchorPane.getChildren().add(button);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(anchorPane));
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нашёл способ, который обходит проблему пункта 1. Вот такой код

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.text.Font;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class FontSample extends Application {
    private DoubleProperty doubleProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(12);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorPane.setPrefSize(900, 700);

        Button button = new Button("MrButton");
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(button, 30.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(button, 30.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(button, 30.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(button, 30.0);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(button);

        button.layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        button.setFont(Font.font(Math.sqrt(newValue.getHeight() * 10)));
    });


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(anchorPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Там формулу вычисления размера шрифта естественно можете сами подобрать, но мне на скорую руку эта подошла, а если ещё немного запариться, то можете сделать практически что хотите...